# Fill a DataTable with one or more "select" command

Tags: c#, mysql

My name is Kenneth, and I'm currently working on this little project of mine. I have stumbled across a problem about filling datatable.

this is my syntax :

```
MySqlDataAdapter view1= new MySqlDataAdapter("reportview_JumlahPerMenu", con);
MySqlDataAdapter view2= new MySqlDataAdapter("reportview_JumlahMenuLaku", con);
lihat_total.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


DataTable dt= new DataTable();
view1.Fill(dt);
view2.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = satu;
```

and this is the result that i got :

[image]

my question is : how to add a column between row [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50R7z.png) and [2]?

n.b : (row[0] is the first row in the picture)

thank you

Comment: Can you be more clear ? what do you mean by adding a column between two rows ?

Comment: this is what i mean : an empty row between row[1] and [2]. this is an example i made via ms.excel : https://ibb.co/3S1WJY2

Comment: Do you mean an empty column if that's what you mean you can add that column manually

Comment: You cannot have empty rows in mysql (in any meaningful or useful way).

Comment: @Shehab, thank you, i really aprecciate your answer but i need spacing between those rows, since i use two different select command, and with different value.. actually it's not for aesthetics, but for better readability for my client. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you join between your tables :

```
SELECT DISTINCT menu.mana_menu     AS Nama_menu, 
            menu_awal.jumlah_porsi AS jumlah_porsi, 
            menu_akhir.porsi_laku  AS Porsi_terjual, 
            menu_akhir.sisa_porsi  AS Porsi_tersisa 
FROM   menu 
   LEFT JOIN menu_awal 
          ON ( menu.id_menu = menu_awal.kode_menu ) 
   LEFT JOIN menu_akhir 
          ON ( menu_awal.jumlah_porsi = menu_akhir.porsi_bawa ) 
ORDER  BY menu_awal.kode_menu ASC;
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, had to go out for a while... tested it, and worked like charm! thank you, shehab, have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add columns in your datatable and set its position like this :

```
dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName", typeof(string)).SetOrdinal(2);
```

Comment: thank you! this is the result : https://ibb.co/V3cMt6r - but i wonder IF i can put the values in now row[4] and [5] to top (not on the bottom as the picture shows) anyways, thank you :)

Comment: I think if you merge the two queries in one query that would be better and more maintainable. or if there's any relations between the two queries you can create master detail relations and show it in your grid

Comment: if you gave me the structure of your two tables and the output you want I can show you how to get the query and make the results you want

Comment: as for database relationship, here it is : https://ibb.co/Wfts8rV (database in indonesian language)

Comment: my bad, i forgot my query..This is the query for my project  https://imgbb.me/i/tUqAL